# Need help on an egrep regex

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I am trying to create an egrep command to grep the number of lines containing a specific text from a text-file but seem to have an error somewhere.

The text-file contains several thousand lines and has the expression `Lastname` in several lines. Problem is, there are also expressions like `xLastname` or `abcLastname` in there which I DON'T want to grab.
So the definition of the RegExpression should look like this:

EITHER there is no text at all in the line before `Lastname` appears
OR there is text in the line BUT a space has to be between the random text and `Lastname`

I tried with `((.+\ )?|(^.))Lastname` and `((.+\ )?|[^.])Lastname` but it always results in the egrep command finding expressions like `abcLastname`.

Where is my mistake? The first part `(.+\ )` ("If there is text, there HAS to be a space afterwards") seems to work fine but the second part ("OR there is no text at all") does not seem to work.

Isn't there a special character that I can use to simply check if whatever comes after it is the FIRST expression/character in the line? I cannot find that information online unfortunately.

Thanks to all of you in advance for your help

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing some examples, but possibly what you want are [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) e.g. `grep -E '\bLastname\b'`

Comment: Or simply `grep -w Lastname` (`-w` means: _"Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words."_).

Comment: I realized it now after over 3 hours with:
((.+\ )|(\ )|^)Lastname

and it seems to finally work.

But thanks a lot for your effort !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to escape spaces, and you don't need to put parens inside an OR expression. So the regex from [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050775/need-help-on-an-egrep-regex#comment1716162_1050775) simplifies to `(.+ | |^)Lastname`.

Now, the space is the important part, so it further simplifies to `( |^)Lastname`, which is practically equivalent to `\bLastname`, where `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

To prevent matches like `LastnameABC`, put another word boundary at the end: `\bLastname\b`. Or you could use grep option `-w`, which matches only whole words. These are equivalent:

```
grep -E '\bLastname\b'
grep -w Lastname
```

<sup>*Credit to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050775/need-help-on-an-egrep-regex#comment1716064_1050775) and [PerlDuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050775/need-help-on-an-egrep-regex#comment1716095_1050775) for suggesting these in the comments*</sup>

The main problem with the regexes in your question is that the first group `(.+ )?` is optional because of the question mark. So `((.+ )?|^.)` simplifies to `(|^.)`. Now because the first part of the OR is null, the whole thing is effectively null. So `(|^.)Lastname` simplifies to just `Lastname`.